# Enumerating posted data in form order in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

Order entry form from Windows CE 6 contains fields with duplicate column names. 
This data needs to be enumerated in ASP.NET MVC4 application in post controller.

Column names are not known in the controller, since the form is created at runtime from user-defined data.

I tried code below, but it returns comma separated values for duplicate names.

How to get every posted key/value pair separately in the order which they appear in the form?
Data can also be posted in json format using jquery, if that can solve the issue.

Observed result:

```
id=1,1,2
orderdate=2013-01-01
quantity=12.2,15
```

Expected result:

```
  id=1
  orderdate=2013-01-01
  id=1
  quantity=12.2
  id=2
  quantity=15
```

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method='post' action='SaveOrder'>

Order id<input name='id' type='text' value='1' />
Date <input name='orderdate' type='date' value='2013-01-01'/>

Row 1 id <input name='id' type='text' value='1' />
Quantity <input name='quantity' type='text' value='12.2'/>

Row 2 id <input name='id' type='text' value='2'/>
Quantity <input name='quantity' type='text' value='15' />

<input type='submit' value='Save order'/>    
</form>
</body></html>
```

Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult SaveOrder(NameValueCollection form) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < form.Count; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(form.GetKey(i)+"="+ form[i].ToString());
}
```

Comment: JSON is going to be your best bet. Your should also get it in the order you're expecting. Have you thought about changing the names though to more clearly group the items together?

Comment: Not sure why JSON would be better. BUT if just change the names you should get the result you want except the id(s) will be printed not as id=1, but for example id1 = 1, orderdate=2013-01-01,  id2=1 etc        Ah I thought the NameValueCollection is not right, it is the FormValueCollection?

Comment: FormValueCollection type does not exist in MVC, why you wrote about it. If this is reasonable, I can parse arrays or change names to unique ones or parse raw post buffer manually. I asked in hope to find better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult SaveOrder()
{
    foreach (string key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
    {
        foreach (string value in Request.Form.GetValues(key))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", key, value);
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Output:

```
id = 1
id = 1
id = 2
orderdate = 2013-01-01
quantity = 12.2
quantity = 15
```

The only thing left for you to do is to reorder the parameters to

```
id = 1
orderdate = 2013-01-01
id = 1
quantity = 12.2
quantity = 15
id = 2
```

Comment: how to reorder parameters to form tab order: names are same. In raw post data they appeas in proper order

Comment: Form.GetValues returns the values of the key in order. You just have to remember that Form.GetValues("id")[0] is the order ID, Form.GetValues("id")[1] is the first row ID and so on.

Comment: The only other possibilities are to change the input names or parse the post data yourself